# New Instagram permissions review "One-off Projects"

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

As a business guy trying to get his first e-commerce site up that simply prints user's Instagram imagery (ie we're not a feed reading app), my developer has now downed tools (rightly) due to his fear about the "One-off project" clause...I could understand Instagram having issues with say an ad agency building something for a temporary, time-limited promotion, but does anyone know whether a genuine, bona fide, long term commercial venture would be excluded under this clause too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the wording on Instagram's developer pages, this would indeed be a valid use case. As they describe on their [permission scopes](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/):

> **To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps:** This use case is meant for apps that allow the general public to login with Instagram to get their own content; for example, an app that allows people to print their own pictures.